# How to add every 3rd row's value (ex: a1, a4, a7, a10, etc) with over 240 entries?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sum, rows, sumifs

I am trying to add the SUM of every 3rd row. I tried manually doing each one (ex: "H8+H11+H14" etc), but Excel halted the execution when I tried that (for 240'ish boxes), and refused to add each cell like that (it was too much for Excel to parse, process and execute).

The rows I want to find the SUM of are (give or take) 245 rows at a time.

```
| APPLICANTS  | # |
| INTERVIEWED | # |
| HIRED       | # |
```

And there are about 245 entries (each with the "Applicants", "Interviewed" fields) of this nature I have to log each instance of.

Thanks in advance for any assistance you guys can provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the cell next to it will always have a specific value or word, you could use =SUMIF(G:G,"HIRED",H:H) for example to SUM all of the values next to any cell with "HIRED".

Answer (score 2):

According to your example you can use an array formula like so:

```
=SUM(H3:H15*--(MOD(ROW(H3:H15),3)=2))
```

Note that array formulas must be confirmed by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> rather than just <kbd>Enter</kbd>

If you need to change *which* row is being targeted, then you can modify the "=2" section to suit.

Comment: Alternative: =SUMPRODUCT(H3:H15*(MOD(ROW(H3:H15),3)=2))