# Sum together every 3rd Cell in a Row

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I would like to sum together every 3rd cell in a row. It would be great to be able to fill down the formula if at all possible. Primarily, I am looking to build this within a VBA script that I have completed other than this one part.

I found the following code, but it doesn't seem to be working:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((MOD(COLUMN(6:6),4)=0)*(6:6))
```

While this is a formula, I feel this should be able to be repeated down and and applied accordingly without any issue. The one problem is that in order to activate the above you would need to Press CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER

Any help to get this so that it would calculate every 3rd cell in a row starting at Column 4 that would be awesome.

Comment: *"every third cell"* then why modulo 4? Provide some example data and example result.

Comment: A search on this site may have helped you solve this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39704466/how-to-add-every-3rd-rows-value-ex-a1-a4-a7-a10-etc-with-over-240-entrie

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following formula to sum every third cell, starting at Column D...

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(MOD(COLUMN(D2:O2)-COLUMN(D2),3)=0),D2:O2)
```

To sum every third cell, starting at the first occurrence of *third* (ie F2)...

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(MOD(COLUMN(D2:O2)-COLUMN(D2)+1,3)=0),D2:O2)
```

Adjust the range accordingly.  Note that the formula can be filled down, and only needs to be confirmed with ENTER, not CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER.

Comment: @pnuts  Slightly shorter, but not as robust. :)  For example, if you insert a column at or prior to Column D, you won't get the desired result.

Comment: I've edited my post to include summing every third cell, starting at the first occurrence of *third* (ie. F2).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148707/discussion-between-domenic-and-pnuts).